# Maven artifact and groupId naming

Tags: maven-2, naming-conventions

I'm currently in the process of moving some project from Ant to Maven. Conformist as I am, I want to use well-established conventions for finding `groupId` and `artifactId`, but I can't find any detailed conventions (there are some, but they don't cover the points I'm wondering about).

Take this project for instance, first the Java package: `com.mycompany.teatimer`

*Tea timer* is actually two words, but the Java package naming conventions forbid the insertion of underscores or hyphens, so I'm writing it all together.

I chose the `groupId` identical to the package ID because I think that's a good idea. Is it?

Finally, I have to pick an `artifactId`, I currently went for `teatimer`. But when I look at other Maven projects, they use hyphens to split words in `artifactId`s, like this: `tea-timer`. But it does look weird when concatenated to the `groupId`: `com.mycompany.teatimer.tea-timer`.

How would you do this?

Another example:

Package name: `com.mycompany.awesomeinhouseframework`

`groupId`: `com.mycompany.awesomeinhouseframework` (?)

`artifactId`: `awesome-inhouse-framework` (?)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Your convention seems to be reasonable. If I were searching for your framework in the Maven repo, I would look for `awesome-inhouse-framework-x.y.jar` in `com.mycompany.awesomeinhouseframework` group directory. And I would find it there according to your convention.

Two simple rules work for me:

- reverse-domain-packages for groupId (since such are quite unique) with all the [constrains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) regarding Java packages names
- project name as artifactId (keeping in mind that it should be jar-name friendly i.e. not contain characters that maybe invalid for a file name or just look weird)

Comment: I find the mixture of non-hyphen (awesomeinhouseframework) and hyphen (awesome-inhouse-framework) spelling a bit strange. Since the groupid does not allow hyphens I would stick with the non hyphen spelling for the artifactid as well.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "jar-name friendly" ?

Comment: The official documentation agrees with you: "Hyphens are perfectly acceptable in groupIds, and you would not need to change your Java package name to match it." https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/coordinates/

Comment: Do we still need the reversed domain for Java standard edition applications; desktop application?.

Answer (score 287):

Weirdness is highly subjective, I just suggest to follow the official recommendation:

> #### [Guide to naming conventions on groupId, artifactId and version](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html)
>
> - **`groupId`** will identify your project uniquely across all projects,
>     so we need to enforce a naming schema.
>     It has to follow the package name
>     rules, what means that has to be at
>     least as a domain name you control,
>     and you can create as many subgroups
>     as you want. [Look at More information
>     about package names](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.7).
>
>   eg. `org.apache.maven`, `org.apache.commons`
>
>   A good way to determine the granularity of the groupId is to use
>     the project structure. That is, if the
>     current project is a multiple module
>     project, it should append a new
>     identifier to the parent's groupId.
>
>   eg. `org.apache.maven`, `org.apache.maven.plugins`,
>     `org.apache.maven.reporting`
> - **`artifactId`** is the name of the jar without version. If you created it
>     then you can choose whatever name you
>     want with lowercase letters and no
>     strange symbols. If it's a third party
>     jar you have to take the name of the
>     jar as it's distributed.
>
>   eg. `maven`, `commons-math`
> - **`version`** if you distribute it then you can choose any typical
>     version with numbers and dots (1.0,
>     1.1, 1.0.1, ...). Don't use dates as they are usually associated with
>     SNAPSHOT (nightly) builds. If it's a
>     third party artifact, you have to use
>     their version number whatever it is,
>     and as strange as it can look.
>
>   eg. `2.0`, `2.0.1`, `1.3.1`

Comment: I know these conventions, but they don't really say how the artifact name should be made up (there are no JAR naming conventions) and what to do if it would be the same as the groupId - I haven't seen a single POM where that is the case.

Comment: @Noarth 1. The artifact name is at your discretion (but using hyphens in the name is a common practice). 2. You're looking for an absolute "rule" that doesn't exist (what if your *awesome inhouse framework* is made of several modules?). See for example the Spring, Maven, Hibernate, etc artifacts.

Comment: No, no I don't have any modules, just simple projects. In fact, we don't have a project called "awesome inhouse framework" :)

Comment: What about `package`? What's the difference to groupId?

Comment: Is the artifactId allowed to have numbers in it?

Comment: @PascalThivent I have no company. I create a maven project in IntelliJ for [SDP course project](https://github.com/al2helal/TextPad). Is there any recommendation to choose these for personal project? I am new in Maven.

Comment: What about "work for hire" situations? Should I choose `groupId` as `com.client.website` or `com.my.website`? According to this answer it should be `com.my.website` since I don't control the client website... but I feel it should be the "site" of the real owner of the code which would mean using `com.client.website` instead.

Comment: @KonstantinK I believe a package is a collection of modules/artifacts. With juts one module in a project, the main package of that project would be the same artifact that one module produces. For multiple modules in one project, the package would include all modules and their artifacts.

Answer (score 115):

Consider the following for building a basic first **Maven** application:

`groupId`

- `com.companyname`

`artifactId`

- `project`

`version`

- 0.0.1

Comment: As a work for hire should I use `com.my.company.project` as `groupId` or `com.client.company.project`?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta you can use any of formate suits you better. Some examples ‘com.companyName.hirePortal’ or ‘org.compnayName.hirePortal’.

Comment: groupId should be  com.companyname not  com.companyname.project

Comment: Not really how it was designed, Apache encourages to add the project/module name in the groupId: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

Answer (score 0):

However, I disagree the official definition of [Guide to naming conventions on groupId, artifactId, and version](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) which proposes the groupId must start with a reversed domain name you control.

`com` means this project belongs to a company, and `org` means this project belongs to a social organization. These are alright, but for those strange domain like xxx.tv, xxx.uk, xxx.cn, it does not make sense to name the groupId started with "tv.","cn.", the groupId should deliver the basic information of the project rather than the domain.

Comment: This convention is preventing developers using maven due to that you must possess a domain before deploying your artifacts to the central maven repository. It is ridiculous. Possessing a domain could be a pretty cost year by year.

Comment: A good practice is to derive package names from the repository URL. If you're using GitHub, your account is called `myuser` and your repository is called `myrepo`, then simply use the package name `com.github.myuser.myrepo`. That's free and still unique.

Comment: The administrators of Maven Central now require using a reversed domain name. https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/coordinates/

Comment: @BasilBourque per the link shared by @ ellen-spertus: "https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/coordinates/" from 2023.06; they now require the ownership of the url conveyed by resulting coordinate of the group.

Comment: @user8395964 Thanks for the update. I deleted my Comment as it is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others, I can recommend avoiding team names as part of group ids. From my experience, projects can often move between teams or a team can be renamed, so that's not good for identifying artifacts.