# What is the archetype to use to build a SpringBoot project?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

For years, I've used Spring Initializr (at https://start.spring.io/) to create the initial SpringBoot application and then modify it to create the app.  This works fine.

**Is there a maven archetype I can use to create a SpringBoot app?**  Or is the Spring Initializr the only way to do this.

Searching I found this:

- [What archetype to choose for a simple java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158348/what-archetype-to-choose-for-a-simple-java-project)

Which shows the command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.apache.maven.archetypes:
```

Which gives me a list of 14 items to choose from.  None of them mention SpringBoot.
The closest match is `org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp`, so I tried it and it created a WebApp (*.war) which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The aim of the Maven archetype is for generating a project skeleton. The Spring Initialiser also does the same but I think you should find it more user friendly to use when compared to executing a maven archetype command.

If you insist to use maven archetype , you can simply search Github to see if there are people share their archetypes (search result at [here](https://github.com/search?q=springboot%20AND%20archetype&type=Repositories))

If your aim is just to use command to generate a spring-boot project skeleton , Spring Initializr actually provide an [HTTP API](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/#api-guide) to do it.

Also you can checkout [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/), which is another tool to generate a spring-boot project skeleton.

Comment: Intellij IDEA has built in Spring Initialiser support

Answer (score 5):

You could also use Spring Boot CLI to scaffold new Spring Boot projects:

```
spring init --dependencies=web,data-jpa my-new-project
```

It works just as Spring Initializr, but on the command line.

See section 2.4 "Initialize a New Project" on Spring Boot CLI documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli.html#cli.using-the-cli.initialize-new-project

Comment: I wish I could have two answers.  This is excellent information.  Thank you