# Maven project groupId === packageId

Tags: maven

In the maven framework, what is the significance of `groupId` when `groupdId` defaults to the `packageId`?

In other works, why bother asking for `groupId` ?

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724415/maven-artifact-and-groupid-naming) which discusses this question, perhaps only tangentially.

Comment: What is the `packageId`? Are you taking about the `artifactId`?

Comment: no referring to artifcatId... when starting up a mvn project we are asked for groupId and then two prompts later.. it asks for a package name which (by default is set to the groupId)..

Comment: @SMV You have been asked for groupId, artifactId and version. Afterwards you have been asked for the Java package name which you like to use...